# How to make private functions in an API?

Tags: c++, api

I currently have the following header file in my API:

```
// my_library.h
namespace MyLibrary
{
    // Private functions
    long bar(long id);
    unsigned long foo(long id);

    // Public functions
    void do_public_thing(long id);
}
```

This header file has implementations for each function in a `my_library.cpp` file. My issue is that I want to make `bar` and `foo` private functions, but still have their implementation in a separate `.cpp` file, so I can't use a blank namespace (at least I don't think so). What should I do?

Comment: You could simply not declare those functions in your API. Maybe have a separate private header for those.

Comment: Or not have a header file for them at all.

Comment: If you want them to be private, they should be in the cpp file only.  That way once you compile the object and give them the header file, they'll never know they exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe best enclosed in an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you should expose your namespace API private functions in the header that does the public part of your API.

What you probably want is

```
// my_library.h
namespace MyLibrary {
    // Public functions
    void do_public_thing(long id);
}
```

---

```
// my_library.cpp
#include library.h

namespace {
    // Private functions
    long bar(long id) {
        // Implementation
    }
    unsigned long foo(long id) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

void MyLibrary::do_public_thing(long id) {
    // Implementation
    long bar_result = bar(id);
    unsingned long foo_result = foo(id);
}
```

The anonymous namespace would protect you from linker ambiguities in case that `bar()` or `foo()` are implemented in any other translation units.